# addEventListener isn't working properly

Tags: javascript

I want to move some elements between two div's. Everything works normal with **onclick** event, but when i swicth to **addEventListener** it lets me switch just a few times the elements.

Here is a previev http://jsfiddle.net/2u6nyxp4/1/  .

Can someone explain why is that ? Thank you.

HTML

```
<div id="one">
  <span>One</span>
  <span>Two</span>
</div>

<div id="two"><span>One</span></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var one = document.getElementById('one');
var two = document.getElementById('two');

var movetoOne = function () {
  one.appendChild(this);
  bindEvents (this,movetoTwo);
}

var movetoTwo = function () {
  two.appendChild(this);   
  bindEvents (this,movetoOne);
}

var bindEvents = function (childList, moveEvent) {
  childList.onclick = moveEvent;

}


for (i=0; i < one.children.length ; i+=1 ) {
  bindEvents(one.children[i], movetoTwo);   
}

for (i=0; i < two.children.length ; i+=1 ) {
    bindEvents(two.children[i], movetoOne);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `oncklick` there is only one event-handler for the event at a time. Each time you call `bindEvents` the old one becomes overwritten by the new one.

If you use `addEventListener`, each time you call `bindEvents` a new handler is **added** to the existing. After ten clicks there are five handlers `movetoOne` and five `movetoTwo` attached to the same element and the browser is totally confused.

The way out: remove the existing handler before adding a new one like so:

```
var bindEvents = function (childList, moveEvent) {
    var old = movetoOne;
    if (old === moveEvent) old = movetoTwo;      
    childList.removeEventListener('click', old);
    childList.addEventListener('click', moveEvent);
}
```

[Working DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/2u6nyxp4/9/). - - - [Reference: removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener).